# Running the suite from jenkins is throwing error of Element not found but same build passes smoothly when run as TestNG suite from Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Running the suite from `jenkins` is throwing error of **Element not found** but same build passes smoothly when run as `TestNG` suite from `Eclipse` IDE.

Below is the error:

> Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='carRegistrationNumber']"}

When I run the same script in `Selenium IDE` and run it via `TestNG` suite it runs smoothly. I have read for solutions online but it's not satisfactory. `Implicit wait` and `Explicit wait` is not an option because the script is just perfect when run via `Eclipse` IDE. Kindly suggest what steps should be taken in such a case.

Comment: How do you know Implicit wait and Explicit wait is not an option here??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur When I run it from Selenium IDE it runs perfectly. So there is no need for sync right? I've already added Implicit & Explicit where ever it was needed.

Comment: Why are you not using `By.id` here instead of `xPath`??? once add the wait, may be this time your network is slow and let me know

Comment: @SaurabhGaur  Still facing the same problem, Tried using id as well. Added explicit wait as well. The script runs very smoothly in IDE but throws error when I run using Jenkins

Comment: Did you confirm that jenkins is pointing to the same test environment that you do when run from Eclipse?  Maybe there's a different build of the product involved.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware Yea I have pointed to the same test environment. I have added the same pom file and the instance of firefox is being launched and few more activities are performed but getting Element not found at the same place every single time.

Comment: What browser? Is the website https or just plain http? Did you try taking a screen snapshot at the point of failure?

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution on `google` and when I tried it worked for me.The problem was due to window resizing issue. When I maximized the window by `driver.manage().window().maximize();` it always threw error. So I changed the window size and the problem that I was facing didn't exist anymore.

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(1382,744);     
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

This is what I set the windows size to and it works completely fine. Don't know why `jenkins` can't find element in maximized windows but this solves for me.